# Disable PowerShell v2 via GPO

Tags: powershell, group-policy, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to disable the old v2 version of PowerShell via GPO but have not been successful.

I have tried everything, to run a Scheduled Task (running a PowerShell script which command inside DOES indeed work if run locally), which included copying the file on the local machine, to setting up a new Software Restriction Policy, but nothing works as that version of PowerShell stays enabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you expand on how disabling the old version should behave? For example, I could run `powershell -version 2 Get-Content -Path 'c:\file.txt'` from powershell 5.1 to parse commands as the older version.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale essentially you shouldn't be able to do that i.e. run commands using the old (v2) version, just the newer ones.

Comment: I assume your goal is to avoid the version downgrade which can disable logging? I'll add that fix as an answer

Comment: @Cpt.Whale we run security scans and having PowerShell v2 enabled came back as a security concerns so we need to disable it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a requirement like this [STIG](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_10/2017-04-28/finding/V-70637):

> Windows PowerShell 5.0 added advanced logging features which can provide additional detail when malware has been run on a system. Disabling the Windows PowerShell 2.0 mitigates against a downgrade attack that evades the Windows PowerShell 5.0 script block logging feature.

The fix is to disable the windows Feature. For example:

```
# Windows 10:
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root

# Windows Server:
Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name PowerShell-V2
```

Uninstalling should take a minute or so, then show you whether a restart is required for the change:

```
Uninstall-WindowsFeature PowerShell-V2

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result                               
------- -------------- ---------      --------------                               
True    No             Success        {Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine}    

# running the command again does not error:

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result                               
------- -------------- ---------      --------------                               
True    No             NoChangeNeeded {}
```

To check the current status:

```
# Windows 10
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root

FeatureName      : MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root
DisplayName      : Windows PowerShell 2.0
Description      : Adds or Removes Windows PowerShell 2.0
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :

# Windows Server:
Get-WindowsFeature -Name PowerShell* 

Display Name                          Name           Install State
------------                          ----           -------------
[X] Windows PowerShell                PowerShellRoot     Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell 5.1        PowerShell         Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine PowerShell-V2      Installed  ## Should be "Available"
    [X] Windows PowerShell ISE        PowerShell-ISE     Installed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I'm encountering the same problem with this as scripts do not have any effect on the machine in my GPO. I don't know why but it looks like the commands are not running. Can you please advise on the correct procedure to make them run correctly?

Comment: I don't know anything about your domain... Is running scripts allowed? How is your GPO configured, and is it even applying? Does the command work when you run it manually? I've added more detail about the powershell side of things to my answer

Comment: running scripts is not allowed on the local machine, but yes the GPO is being applied as I tested something else on it. Basically, I just need to run one simple PowerShell command on all machines but the script won't even start

Comment: @sysadmin0101 *How* is running scripts not allowed, via default execution policy? You can try to use GPO > scheduled task > Start a program > `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -f \\path\to\script.ps1`, like this: https://4sysops.com/archives/run-powershell-scripts-as-immediate-scheduled-tasks-with-group-policy/ , But it will leave behind a scheduled task to clean up. Alternatively, you could just change the execution policies through GPO as well, though I **don't** recommend it.